# How to manipulate tables / dataframe from input in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm quite new in shiny, and I'm struggling with reactive objects and dataframe in shiny.

I'd like to make an app which allows the user to load a file (like .csv , .rds etc) which will be the "base" of all the process after. The idea is that once the file is uploaded, some panels will display subsets of the table uploaded or new tables made of calculations based on the uploaded table.

Actually the difficulty is about the synthax, especialy how to select rows and columns from the table. I'm searching for an equivalent of df[c(1,2),] or df[,c(1,2)] or df$variable_name in shiny.

Here is my code, I just want to display the 1st and 2nd column of the input file in order to see if the processing that I've done is ok :

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions

library(sas7bdat)


ui <-fluidPage(navlistPanel(
  tabPanel("Welcome",textOutput("welcome_message"),textOutput("welcome_message_2"),img(src="logo_danone.jpg", height = 350, width = 350)),

  tabPanel("Input files", fileInput("file1", "Choose File",
                                    accept = c(
                                      "text/csv",
                                      "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                      ".csv")),
           inputPanel(
             tableOutput("contents")

           )),

  tabPanel("AUC Derivation",tableOutput("selection")),

  tabPanel("AUC Derivation plots"),

  tabPanel("Shape Analysis"),

  tabPanel("Tables"),

  tabPanel("Plots"),

  tabPanel("Clustering"),

  tabPanel("tab1",dataTableOutput("value")),

  tabPanel("tab2",plotOutput("hist"))






))

server <-function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$file, e.g.

  output$welcome_message <- renderText("test")
  output$welcome_message_2 <- renderText("logo")

  output$value <- renderDataTable({
    iris
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    readRDS(inFile$datapath)
  })

  output$selection <- reactive({return(input$file1[,c(1,2)])})

  #output$selected <- renderTable({selection()})

  output$hist <- renderPlot({     # Refers  to putputs with output$<id>
    ggplot2::ggplot(data = iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot() # Refers to inputs with input$<id>
  })

}

  shinyApp(ui, server)
#}
```

Does anyone can explain me how to manipulate uploaded tables through shiny ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to give a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example by giving a piece of code creating a small csv file, that you want to upload in your shiny app. This way, anybody can reproduce the example you give

Comment: @denis I've posted the reproductible example below with .csv file

Answer (score 0):

@denis :here's a reproductible example with .csv  [csv file](https://gofile.io/?c=qXY886)

What I want to know is how to manipulate and subset the input csv (which is a data frame) because I will have to filter, merge and use columns through already written functions and display the results in different panels

```
 ## Only run examples in interactive R sessions

library(sas7bdat)


ui <-fluidPage(navlistPanel(
  tabPanel("Welcome",textOutput("welcome_message"),textOutput("welcome_message_2"),img(src="logo_danone.jpg", height = 350, width = 350)),

  tabPanel("Input files", fileInput("file1", "Choose File",
                                    accept = c(
                                      "text/csv",
                                      "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                      ".csv")),
           inputPanel(
             tableOutput("contents")

           )),

  tabPanel("AUC Derivation",tableOutput("selection")),

  tabPanel("AUC Derivation plots"),

  tabPanel("Shape Analysis"),

  tabPanel("Tables"),

  tabPanel("Plots"),

  tabPanel("Clustering"),

  tabPanel("tab1",dataTableOutput("value")),

  tabPanel("tab2",plotOutput("hist"))






))

server <-function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$file, e.g.

  output$welcome_message <- renderText("test")
  output$welcome_message_2 <- renderText("logo")

  output$value <- renderDataTable({
    iris
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, sep = ";")
  })

  output$selection <- reactive({return(input$file1[,c(1,2)])})

  #output$selected <- renderTable({selection()})

  test <- reactive({input$file1()})

  output$hist <- renderPlot({     # Refers  to putputs with output$<id>
    ggplot2::ggplot(data = iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot() # Refers to inputs with input$<id>
  })

}

  shinyApp(ui, server)
#}
```